# install4j launcher classpath issue using scan folders in Arch Linux

Tags: install4j

We are getting reports of the classpath not being constructed correctly by the install4j application launcher when using scan folders, that is folders where all the jar files should be included in the classpath.

The problem happens on Arch Linux after the latest version of grep (or fgrep) was installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a regression in GNU grep 2.19. install4j 5.1.12 will fix this issue.